# My CNN model is predicting with 100% confidence and only one class

Tags: python, keras, multi-class

I am training my CNN image classification model with keras and tensorflow backend. It has two outputs: dog, cat. I trained it with 12k images per class and then convert it from .h5 to .mlmodel for Apples CoreML for use in my iOS application. 
After I train my model, in my app no matter what picture I give the model it predicts only one class and with 100% confidence. I once managed to get a picture that it predicted was 100% cat and 14% dog. But it mostly just predicts that it's a cat. 
I am stuck now as to why it is doing that. I hope that someone can help me figure this out.
Here is my keras code:

```
# importing libraries 
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator 
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D 
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense 
from keras import backend as K 

img_width, img_height = 224, 224

train_data_dir = 'data/train/'
validation_data_dir = 'data/validate/'
nb_train_samples = 100
nb_validation_samples = 20
epochs = 20
batch_size = 10

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first': 
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height) 
else: 
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3) 

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (2, 2), input_shape = input_shape)) 
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size =(2, 2))) 

model.add(Conv2D(32, (2, 2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size =(2, 2))) 



model.add(Flatten()) 
model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.summary()

model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
                optimizer = 'adam', 
                metrics = ['accuracy']) 

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator() 

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir, 
                              target_size =(img_width, img_height), 
                     batch_size = batch_size, class_mode ='binary') 

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory( 
                                    validation_data_dir, 
                   target_size =(img_width, img_height), 
          batch_size = batch_size, class_mode ='binary') 

model.fit_generator(train_generator, 
    steps_per_epoch = nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs = epochs, validation_data = validation_generator, 
    validation_steps = nb_validation_samples // batch_size) 

model.save('ModelsH5/catndog_small.h5')
print("DONE")
```

Comment: Image cannot be 100% cat and 14% dog with sigmoid output, the probabilities need to sum up to 1.
Also, with single sigmoid neuron as output, I would expect binary_crossentropy loss instead of sparse_categorical_crossentropy (I am not sure on the exact effect of using sparse_categorical_crossentropy tho).

Comment: I have two output neurons. (or atleast I think I do, because the last layer is dense(2)). I am not using binary_crossentropy, because with it I cant have two output neurons. I dont understand this very well. If you could give some bit of guidance, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Ok, so I assume that you are performing classification - that image is either dog or cat, and cannot be both? If so, you should use either one output neuron (which value would be the probability that the image is cat, and the probability of dog will be implicitely 1 - probability of cat). Equivalently, you can use softmax layer instead of sigmoid (you would need softmax for more than two classes anyway).
With 2 sigmoid neuron as output, the probabilities of all classes will not sum up to 1 (so they cannot be interpreted as a probability distribution.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try to edit my code with softmax layer. I must have 2 output neurons for my iOS app to interpret them correctly.

Comment: I edited my code and set my last layer to softmax. Now it predicts every output as 50% sure. Both training and validation accuracy is stuck at 0.5.